# How to print the current working directory's php version in a dual environment

Tags: php, linux, bash, .htaccess, shell

On a Linux server with multiple versions of php installed, I am looking for a simple command to show me the version of php being used for the current working directory through command line.

At first I tried simply using

```
php -v
```

but that apparently only shows the default php version for the server rather than the one set by .htaccess for the current directory.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use <?php phpinfo() ?> I mean; I know it's not an answer to your question, but it might be simpler to use...

Comment: When you run php via commandline there is no webserver (nginx, apache) involved. To run a different version you simply call another executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add a php page in the current directory with the following in it.

```
< ?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The browse to the page name which could be something like version.php and it will be displayed.

Also, I guess if you have access to the .htaccess file, you could always run a grep for the AddHandler, this will state what php version is being used for the directory the .htaccess file is in.

```
$ grep AddHandler .htaccess
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Otherwise, I know of no other command to do this without already knowing the php version and pointing to the correct php command in /bin. I hope this helps.

Comment: That's pretty much what I have been trying. Short of using a phpinfo(), which can tell me the current working directory's effective php version even if there is no .htaccess in that directory, I haven't quite found out how phpinfo() does it. Ideally I would do a 
   find -name '.htaccess' exec grep -EHo 'AddHandler'
(or something along those lines) and have it only send me the line from the .htaccess in the current directory or the next directory before it that has an .htaccess file with that line in it. So far I am just too new to bash to even begin to think of a proper way to do that.